# What is omitted here?

Tags: conditional-constructions, ellipsis

**Political power, *used* right, will produce good results.**

"used right" means "if it is used right?"

Comment: Always put the source or some explanation. Is this you read somewhere or you made it? Perfectly framed questions not only help learn us better but also maintain this site's credit.

Comment: That's what it means, but I don't think anything is omitted.

Comment: @user4550 Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: There's a strong argument for saying OP's "used right" is *not* in fact "used ***correctly***" here. At the very least it should probably be ***rightly***, though even the collocation *"power used rightly"* only gets a dozen hits on Google Books (but *"power used right"* gets less than half that). In short, the correct word is ***correctly***, not ***right***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Using *right* as an adverb meaning "correctly" is standard.  See e.g. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/right), sense 21.  It is true that neither *used right* nor *used rightly* is common, however.

Comment: @snailplane: I didn't mean to imply that I personally have any objection to the "flat adverb" usage in general. And maybe 12 hits to 5 is too small to have any significance - but my gut feel was the kind of writers who would refer to *using power right/rightly* would probably be the kind who would prefer the first version, and GB obviously doesn't contradict that. They're all weirdos to me anyway, since they should be using *correctly* in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I understand, as you suggest, that it can stand for:

- > Political power if it is used right will produce good results.

Other alternatives:

- > Political power when it is used right will produce good results.
- > Political power when it is exercised right will produce good results.
- Or as suggested by @starsplusplus:

  > Political power that is used right will produce good results.

Comment: Or "political power that is used right will produce good results".